# Html - From checkbox to combobox

Tags: html, forms, combobox, checkbox, boolean

In the web app I am currently developing I have a form, and one of the fields is a boolean "IsFixedCost" (true/false).

The natural way, to me, to represent it on the form is with a checkbox: FixedCost? (checked = true, unchecked = false).

My boss forced me to change it in a combobox: FixedCost? -> option1: Fixed, option2: Variable

because he says that "it's more clear and understandable".

I find it totally senseless (because if it isn't fixed, it's variable, no other possibilities) and less usable (requires 2 clicks to change instead of one)

I'd like to hear opinions about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for checkboxes, since a multiple choice combobox (I assume you mean select) is less accessible. In other words... Your boss is wrong. Radio buttons is to be avoided since they're not accessible.

Comment: That's exactly what I think. Still I'd love to hear more opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you are correct, it isn't 100% obvious.  Remember your application has to cater for the lowest common denominator (i.e. the stupidist person needs to be able to use it.)

Comment: True. I'd prefer two radio buttons though instead of a combobox/dropdown, as it saves one click and also always shows you all possibilities rather than hiding the unselected options.

Comment: I'd like to know why all other checkboxes on the page are good as they are, but not this one.

Also, a combobox is thought to represent data that has a one-to-many relationship, while checkboxes to represent boolean fields.

I mean, a combobox with 2 fixed options true/false is totally meaningless..

Comment: But it isn't true/false, its fixed/variable. Obviously `fixed?` fits, however do people know for sure that `variable = !fixed`? In your database you should certainly have a bool field, however for users you need to spell out both options.